# Persistent bottom sheets in material design

Tags: material-design, bottom-navigation

I'm designing an application with a bottom navigation.

In one of the views the user may click on a floating action button which opens a page containing a form to fill; and this form page I'm referring to does not have the bottom navigation.

I would like to use a persistent bottom sheet on this page, as long as the user can add rows or attach something or other actions that are related to this form (as the persistent bottom sheets are "to display content equal in value to the primary content" as google states). **Will it be confusing?**

[image]

Of course the icons on the bottom navigation and persistent bottom sheet are different, so it won't be a confusion due to similar icons.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve on the form page (google.com/forms but it's on the web):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not navigation, the button is performing an action, the action being to add a form to fill.

The navigation stays at the bottom in the same place as the previous page, as long as you're not changing that between pages, it reads fine to me.

Comment: I'm aware it's not a navigation as I stated in my question that these are actions like adding a row or attach something, etc. But my question is if the users understand the difference too? or they confuse it with the bottom navigation?!

Comment: You'd have to ask your users, as I said, it looks fine to me.

Comment: agreed with @DarrylGodden it looks fine, just test it on your users to answer the other part of your question they will give you a more reliable answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be confusing and the users may not want to use the actions of the form because they are "scared" of a change of context like when they click on the navigation bar in other pages.

Just be sure that the differences between the two menus are clear (like you did in the pictures, with the shadows on one of them) and all should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Subjectively speaking, I wouldn't find it confusing—the visual distinction is clear enough and, more importantly, the meaning of the icons would hopefully set me straight. (For example, I would assume the "bold" icon gives me bold text, rather than taking me to a page about bold text.)

That said, if you want to be sure, make some high-fidelity mockups and test these screens out.